# static content deploy issues

Tags: magento2, php, static-content

I'm having major issues with the static content deploy command because it doesn't give any errors but it isn't fixing my issue. Here is what my website looks like currently:

[image: static content deploy doesn't work]

Here are the results of what I have tried:

- Magento compile (no errors)
- Magento setup:upgrade (no errors)
- Magento static content deploy (no errors)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS and CSS minification  were turned on and that was causing the static content deploy to not work for some reason so I turned all minification off and tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these Admin settings can have a major impact on performance. I had an issue with a lot of JavaScript errors that were showing in the Developer Tools console. Enabling "Merge JavaScript Files" from Admin >> Store > Configuration >> Developer fixed most of them.